# suma de columna de una tabla con react

Tags: reactjs

Que tal me gustaría que me ayudaran a poder sumar la columna  de una tabla en react que se muestre automáticamente al mostrar los datos. Soy nuevo en el desarrollo con React y me he topado con esta problemática.

saludos.

este es mi código que estoy implementando.

muestro mi cabecera de la tabla.

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>CODIGO</th>
    <th>CONCEPTO</th>
    <th>MARCA</th>
    <th className="text-center">CANTIDAD</th>
    <th>UNIDAD</th>
    <th className="text-right">P.U.MXN</th>
    <th className="text-right">DESCUENTO</th>
    <th className="text-right">IMPORTE</th>
    <th className="text-right">P.U.USD</th>
    <th className="text-right">COD. FISCAL</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Aquí lleno mi tabla.

```html
<tbody>
   {Object.keys(products).map((key) => (
       <tr key={products[key].id}>
          <td>{products[key].codigo_fabrica}</td>
          <td>{products[key].descripcion}</td>
          <td>{products[key].marca}</td>
          <td>{products[key].cantidad}</td>
          <td>{products[key].unidad}</td>
          <td>${products[key].precio}</td>
          <td>{/* <input/> */}</td>
          <td>{/* <input/> */}</td>
          <td>{/* <input/> */}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
             <button onClick={() => removeProduct(key)} className="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"/></button>
          </td>
       </tr>
    )}
</tbody>
```

en esta parte es dónde quiero mostrar los resultados de la suma.

```html
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colSpan={7} className="text-right">
      <strong>TOTAL</strong>
    </td>
    <td className="text-right">
      <strong>$ </strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defines una variable que guarde el total:

```
render() {
  let total = 0;
  //...
```

luego en la iteración de productos vas sumando el total (asumo cantidad + precio):

```
   {Object.keys(products).map((key) => {
       total += products[key].cantidad * products[key].precio
       return (<tr key={products[key].id}>
          <td>{products[key].codigo_fabrica}</td>
          <td>{products[key].descripcion}</td>
          <td>{products[key].marca}</td>
          <td>{products[key].cantidad}</td>
          <td>{products[key].unidad}</td>
          <td>${products[key].precio}</td>
          <td>{/* <input/> */}</td>
          <td>{/* <input/> */}</td>
          <td>{/* <input/> */}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
             <button onClick={() => removeProduct(key)} className="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"/></button>
          </td>
       </tr>);
    }}
```

Y al final agregas el total acumulado:

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colSpan={7} className="text-right">
      <strong>TOTAL</strong>
    </td>
    <td className="text-right">
      <strong>$ {total} </strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```